# Make Powershell CLI (environment) variables available in PHP

Tags: php, windows, powershell, variables, environment-variables

I want to be able to access environment variables set in Powershell from within my PHP script.

Normally in Linux systems `export SOMETHING=foo` would work and in Windows CMD `SET SOMETHING=bar` would also work. But I don't know how to make this work with Powershell CLI (not script) as well.

I have tried using `Set-Variable -Name "SOMETHING" -Value "foo"`, but that didn't get read by PHP.

Within my PHP script I simply want to use `getenv('SOMETHING');`.

Comment: [environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("myName", "myValue",  [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

Comment: `New-Item Env:/SOMETHING -Value "foo"`

Comment: @Clijsters your solution worked! You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create environment variables in PowerShell. It is important to distinguish between *PowerShell variables* (e.g. `$myVar`) and *Environment variables* as you might know them from the good old command prompt (e.g. in cmd `SET MYVAR=MYVAL`).

To create an *environment* variable in PowerShell, the easiest way is to create a new Item in the environment (`Env`):

```
New-Item Env:/VarName -Value "Foo"
```

The code example you posted

```
Set-Variable -Name "Name" -Value "value"
```

creates a *PowerShell variable*, but it's easier to just write `$Name = "value"`.

PowerShell variables are only visible in your PowerShell scope. Environment variables can be read by any program you start as a sub process in the current environment (e.g. PowerShell session).

EDIT:

The example posted in the comments by [@f64a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4037258/f6a4) is interesting too:

```
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("myName", "myValue",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

It is afaik the only way to manipulate environment variables via PowerShell out of your own scope. With [`EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.8#System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_Machine) you can choose where your variable is manipulated. Be aware that you might need higher privileges to manipulate these.